# Build query for this project for resulting available seats

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation

```
TABLE A
==============

A.eID , A.memberID.   

-----------------


TABLE B
==============

B.eID , B.guestID
-----------------



TABLE C
==============

C.eID , C.availableseats
-----------------
```

**Required output**

```
TABLE D
==============

D.eID , Balance seats (C.available seats - count(A.memberID) + count(B.memberID)
```

---

Table A represents eventID and member ID , B shows event ID and guestID
Need to count total number of members and total number of guests for each event , then subtract from available seats .

So far, I tried :

```
SELECT Count(eventguest.memberid) + x AS total, Y.eventid 
  FROM ( SELECT Count(eventmember.memberid) AS X, eventmember.eventid 
           FROM eventmember 
          GROUP BY eventid ) Y 
 INNER JOIN eventguest 
    ON Y.eventid = eventguest.eventid 
 GROUP BY Y.eventid
```

Comment: Any code you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, tried this.. But wrong..                    /n    SELECT Count(eventguest.memberid) + x AS total, 
    Y.eventid 
FROM   
(
 SELECT Count(eventmember.memberid) AS X, 
       eventmember.eventid 
 FROM   eventmember 
 GROUP  BY eventid
) Y
INNER JOIN eventguest 
ON Y.eventid = eventguest.eventid 
GROUP  BY Y.eventid

Answer (score 1):

You may need something like this:

```
select c.dId, c.availableSeats - count(a.memberId) - count(b.guestId)
from table_c c
    left join table_b b
        on(b.eId = c.eId)
    left join table_a a
        on(a.eId = c.eId)
group by c.dId, c.availableSeats
```

Comment: Hi, this query generated output, but when i checked the answer - its not correct.  say like one event have 20 seats , membercount = 2 and guest count = 1 , remaining seats should be shown. as 17 - but my result shows 16

Comment: Please post some sample data, so that we can reproduce the issue and find the right way. Without data, it's hard to understand what you need